# Billboard in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I was trying to make a billboard using LWJGL and I succeeded partially. The quad appears and does face the camera when I strafe. However, as soon as I rotate the camera on any of the axises the quad also moves along the axises in different manners. Here is the code I use:

```
/***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
 * All rendering happens here...
 **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
private void render() {

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
    GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The View

    //GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_POSITION, lightPosition); // Position The Light

    GL11.glRotatef(360.0f - yrot, 0, 1.0f, 0);
    GL11.glRotatef(lookupdown, 1.0f, 0, 0);

    GL11.glTranslatef(-xpos, 0, -zpos);


    GL11.glCallList(blocksList);
    GL11.glCallList(tilesList);
    GL11.glCallList(roofList);

    /* Render billboards */
    Billboard bb = lvLoader.currentLevel.billboards[0];
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glRotatef(360.0f - yrot, 0, -1.0f, 0);
    GL11.glRotatef(lookupdown, -1.0f, 0, 0);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glVertex3f(bb.origin.x + 0.5f, bb.origin.y + 0.5f, bb.origin.z);
    GL11.glVertex3f(bb.origin.x - 0.5f, bb.origin.y + 0.5f, bb.origin.z);
    GL11.glVertex3f(bb.origin.x - 0.5f, bb.origin.y - 0.5f, bb.origin.z);
    GL11.glVertex3f(bb.origin.x + 0.5f, bb.origin.y - 0.5f, bb.origin.z);
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

Here are the functions controlling lookupdown and yrot.

```
if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) { // Is PageUp Being Pressed?
        lookupdown -= 1.0f; // Rotate The Secene Downwards
    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) { // Is PageDown Being Pressed?
        lookupdown += 1.0f; // Rotate The Scene Upwards
    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT))
    {
        yrot -= 1.5f; // Rotate The Scene To The Left
    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT))
    {
        yrot += 1.5f; // Rotate The Scene To The Left
    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W))
    {
        adjustXZ((float) Math.sin(yrot * piover180) * 0.05f, (float) Math.cos(yrot * piover180) * 0.05f, false, false);
    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S))
    {
        adjustXZ((float) Math.sin(yrot * piover180) * 0.05f, (float) Math.cos(yrot * piover180) * 0.05f, true, true);
    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D))
    {
        adjustXZ((float) Math.sin((yrot-90) * piover180) * 0.05f, (float) Math.cos((yrot-90) * piover180) * 0.05f, false, false);
    }

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
    {
        adjustXZ((float) Math.sin((yrot+90) * piover180) * 0.05f, (float) Math.cos((yrot+90) * piover180) * 0.05f, false, false);
    }

private void adjustXZ(float x, float z, boolean xAdd, boolean zAdd)
{
    if (collisionCheck(x, z, xAdd, zAdd))
        return;

    if (xAdd)
        xpos += x;
    else if (!xAdd)
        xpos -= x;

    if (zAdd)
        zpos += z;
    else if (!zAdd)
        zpos -= z;
}
```

Comment: Could you give a little clarification on where you get `yrot` and  `lookupdown`? It looks like those might be values for the camera, but it's hard to be sure without more info.

Comment: Yes, they control the camera. Added them to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with LWJGL so I'm not 100% sure what it expects, but based on my experience with other 3D API's it sounds very much like you've got your matrix transforms in the wrong order.

Try changing your code as follows:

```
GL11.glPushMatrix();
GL11.glTranslatef(bb.origin.x, bb.origin.y, bb.origin.z); // Translation here
GL11.glRotatef(360.0f - yrot, 0, -1.0f, 0);
GL11.glRotatef(lookupdown, -1.0f, 0, 0);
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0); // No translation here anymore
GL11.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0;
GL11.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
GL11.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
GL11.glEnd();
```

On a separate note, you're not using a conventional billboarding technique. Rather than having the billboards always face the camera, you're having them always be perpendicular to the camera. This will be noticeable for billboard objects near the edges of your view frustrum. I'll leave it up to you to look into this further though!

Comment: Thanks, this did solve the problem. I really need to get a better understanding on how the translations and rotations work in openGL. Maybe you have some articles on this?
Perpendicular billboards will be enough for my little project, I think, but I will research this matter further.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sorry, not sure I can be much help with sourcing articles/tutorials. It's a while since I worked with OpenGL directly since I'm more of a gameplay programmer than a graphics programmer. There is a lot of stuff out there though, just get googling and sooner or later you'll come across a site or two with decent tutorials that suit your learning style and level of experience... Good luck!